# Add callback to pressing the hold button in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect when home button is pressed iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324596/detect-when-home-button-is-pressed-ios)

I need to know when user presses the hold button while using my app and run a method after that. How can I do that?

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754317/is-it-possible-to-distinguish-between-locking-the-device-and-sending-an-app-to-b

Comment: hold button? home button?

Comment: No, I meant a hold button. #6 from http://0.tqn.com/d/ipod/1/0/Q/I/-/-/iphone-4s-anatomy.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the duplicate I posted, the only events you can respond to (regardless of which button actually triggers the behaviour) are the application lifecycle events;

See the additional explanation here;

[Is it possible to distinguish between locking the device and sending an app to background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754317/is-it-possible-to-distinguish-between-locking-the-device-and-sending-an-app-to-b)